# Comparing dates in Excel and adding a set of cells

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, sum, array-formulas

I am trying to compare a series of cells in a column to match a particular month and if it matches, I want to add the value from a particular cell.

For example, If the month value in A1 to A50 is December, I want to add C1 to C50. If anything in between A1 to A50 is not December, then it would add 0 for that particular cell.

I was able to implement it by using sum, if and month commands. But, I was not able to use arrays to check the month, which is making the formula complicated and huge for a large number of cells.

Is it possible to use an array to implement this.

```
=sum(if(month(A1)=9, C1, 0),if(month(A2)=9, C2, 0))
```

Comment: Are all the dates in the same year?  does year matter if not?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A50)=9)*(C1:C50))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This formula works by applying an array of 50 **1**s and **0**s to the array of **C** values.  Just add addition terms to further restrict the values being added.  For example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A50)=9)*(YEAR(A1:A50)=2018)*(A1:A50<>"")*(C1:C50))
```

will only keep 2018 records in the sum and will not include any blank records.

Comment: @Roger  See my **EDIT#1**